# Room autogenerate

Tags: android, android-room

Как сделать чтобы у меня автоматически генерировался id?

```
@Entity(tableName = "MessagesDetails")
public class MessageDetails {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private Integer id;
private int authorId;
private String title;
private String text;
private String date;
private String time;

public MessageDetails(Integer id, int authorId, String title, String text, String date, String time) {
    this.id = id;
    this.authorId = authorId;
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer value) { 
    this.id = value; 
}
```

Теоретически это должно работать, но у меня не работает, или же я что-то неправильно пишу. Что я должен сделать, чтобы сгенерировался id? Как инициализировать новый объект? Пытался что-то типо такого(хотя как я только не пытался):

```
MessageDetails messageDetails1 = new MessageDetails(0,2,
            "title1", "text1", UtilHelper.getDate(), UtilHelper.getTime());
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: серия [уроков по Room](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html) на русском. там все очень подробно объясняется

Comment: @pavlofff Посмотрю, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey.html#autogenerate) написано, что специальными значениями, указывающими необходимость генерировать ключ являются:

- для примитивных `int` и `long` - это `0`
- для боксов `Integer` и `Long` - это `null`

В Вашем случае нужно передавать в конструктор `null`, либо заменить тип первичного ключа на примитив:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
```

Comment: Т.е. потом я смогу инициализировать объект через Message msg = new Message(null, ...)? Или он генерирует только во время Insert? Просто я так делал, пытался как-то отследить и не получалось.

Comment: Ключ генерирует `SQLite` при вставке и выдаёт его как результат успешной операции. Я как-то не задавался вопросом -  обновляет ли `Room` вставляемый объект - но если метод вставки объявить с возвращаемым типом `long` - то он вернёт сгенерированный ключ и Вы сможете обновить `id` в объекте сами.

Comment: Ты прав. Уже сделал, спасибо за помощь)